# Object of type MultipleObjectsReturned is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I've been receiving this error from our crash reporting service in Django, I have not been able to replicate the issue but it happens several times a day apparently without crashing the web app, any hints on where to look will be appreciated, I've been stuck on this for a week now

```
Internal Server Error: /api/v1/users/

TypeError at /api/v1/users/
Object of type MultipleObjectsReturned is not JSON serializable

Request Method: POST
Request URL: url_hidden_for_security/api/v1/users/
Django Version: 3.0.2
Python Executable: /layers/google.python.pip/pip/bin/python3
Python Version: 3.7.10
Python Path: ['/srv', '/workspace', '/layers/google.python.pip/pip/bin', '/opt/python3.7/lib/python37.zip', '/opt/python3.7/lib/python3.7', '/opt/python3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.7/site-packages', '/opt/python3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages']
Server time: Mon, 19 Jul 2021 17:55:33 +0000
HTTP_FORWARDED = 'for="107.178.232.186";proto=https'
HTTP_HOST = 'hidden_for_security'
HTTP_TRACEPARENT = '00-aea37beca4053cbf1b25e7faaafb2f5a-1a505df1a2c1a721-01'
HTTP_UID = 'KwycJTu7EVYmbXk8lXdEqgSk3Fd2'
HTTP_USER_AGENT = 'axios/0.21.1'
HTTP_X_APPENGINE_API_TICKET = 'ChA1YzBhODFiYWM5ZjE4MGZkGhMIv7W5ptrv8QIVPmnFAR15+Qin'
HTTP_X_APPENGINE_CITY = '?'
HTTP_X_APPENGINE_CITYLATLONG = '0.000000,0.000000'
HTTP_X_APPENGINE_COUNTRY = 'US'
HTTP_X_APPENGINE_DEFAULT_VERSION_HOSTNAME = 'hidden_for_security'
HTTP_X_APPENGINE_HTTPS = 'on'
HTTP_X_APPENGINE_REGION = '?'
HTTP_X_APPENGINE_REQUEST_LOG_ID = '60f5bc9500ff05cb7f3760baec0001737e617564696f2d63617264696f2d31363665320001323032313037313374313432373432000100'
HTTP_X_APPENGINE_TIMEOUT_MS = '599999'
HTTP_X_APPENGINE_USER_IP = '107.178.232.186'
HTTP_X_CLOUD_TRACE_CONTEXT = 'aea37beca4053cbf1b25e7faaafb2f5a/1896118735522080545;o=1'
HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR = '107.178.232.186, 169.254.1.1'
HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO = 'https'
PATH_INFO = '/api/v1/users/'
QUERY_STRING = ''
RAW_URI = '/api/v1/users/'
REMOTE_ADDR = '127.0.0.1'
REMOTE_PORT = '64512'
REQUEST_METHOD = 'POST'
SCRIPT_NAME = ''
SERVER_NAME = '0.0.0.0'
SERVER_PORT = '8081'
SERVER_PROTOCOL = 'HTTP/1.1'
SERVER_SOFTWARE = 'gunicorn/20.0.4'
gunicorn.socket = <socket.socket fd=10, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, laddr=('127.0.0.1', 8081), raddr=('127.0.0.1', 64512)>
wsgi.errors = <gunicorn.http.wsgi.WSGIErrorsWrapper object at 0x3ebf8554ce90>
wsgi.file_wrapper = ''
wsgi.input = <gunicorn.http.body.Body object at 0x3ebf85567c50>
```

I've omitted some of the stack trace for security reasons but this is the view that's causing this issue:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
@permission_classes([IsUserAuthenticated, IsUserAdmin])
def get_users(request):
    limit = int(request.GET.get('limit', 0))
    offset = int(request.GET.get('offset', 0))
    first_name = request.GET.get('first_name', '')
    last_name = request.GET.get('last_name', '')
    email = request.GET.get('email', '')
    paid = request.GET.get('paid', '')
    gender = request.GET.get('gender', '')
    country = request.GET.get('country', '')
    sign_in_device = request.GET.get('sign_in_device', '')
    coupon = request.GET.get('coupon', '')
    company_name = request.GET.get('company_name', None)
    ordering_attribute = request.GET.get('ordering_attribute', 'firebase_sign_up_date')
    ordering_attribute = 'firebase_sign_up_date' if ordering_attribute == '' else ordering_attribute
    ordering_sequence = request.GET.get('ordering_sequence', 'desc')
    ordering_sequence = 'desc' if ordering_sequence == '' else ordering_sequence

    filters = {
        'first_name__icontains': first_name, 'last_name__icontains': last_name, 'email__icontains': email
        , 'gender__startswith': gender, 'country__icontains': country,
        'sign_in_device__startswith': sign_in_device, 'coupons__icontains': coupon
    }
    if company_name:
        filters['company_name__icontains'] = company_name

    users = User.objects.filter(**filters)
    if paid == 'Yes':
        users = users.filter(Q(in_app_payment=True) | Q(in_app_payment_ios=True) | Q(subscribed=True))
    elif paid == 'No':
        users = users.filter(in_app_payment=False, in_app_payment_ios=False, subscribed=False)
    total_users = users.count()
    if ordering_sequence == 'desc':
        users = users.order_by(F(ordering_attribute).desc(nulls_last = True))[offset: offset + limit]
    else:
        users = users.order_by(F(ordering_attribute).asc(nulls_last = True))[offset: offset + limit]
    users = users.values()
    return Response(Helper.success_response(
        'Successfully fetched users',
        {
            "total_users": total_users,
            "users": list(users)
        }
    ))
```

succues_response method for anyone wondering

```
def success_response(cls, status, data, status_code=HTTP_200_OK):
    """Sends success response dictionary"""
     return {
            'status': status,
            'status_code': status_code,
            'data': data
            }
```

The User Modal

```
class User(models.Model):
    class Meta:
      db_table = "users"
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    birth_year = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    uid = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, default='')
    in_app_payment = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    in_app_payment_ios = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    subscribed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    provider = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, default='')
    firebase_sign_up_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    sign_up_device = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, default='')
    sign_in_device = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, default='')
    country = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, default='')
    company_name = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    coupons = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=200), blank=True, default=list)
```

Comment: You've omitted the useful part of your stacktrace.

Comment: I've added the full stacktrace, just omitted the base URL

Comment: Sorry- do you have the large python trace available that contains pointers to specific lines? The server agent details likely aren't relevant.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, that's been the main issue, If I had that, this might've been resolved quickly, I'll have to look into our production environment to determine if it's keeping any logs with specific error lines in the project